# Python 3 - Comparing two lists, finding out if el is in list, based on "starts with"

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two lists:

```
items_on_queue = ['The rose is red and blue', 'The sun is yellow and round']
things_to_tweet = ['The rose is red','The sun is yellow','Playmobil is a toy']
```

I want to find out if an element is present on both lists based on the FEW CHARACTERS AT THE BEGINNING, and delete the element from things_to_tweet if a match is found.

The final output should be things_to_tweet = ['Playmobil is a toy']

Any idea how I can do this?
Thank you

PS/ I tried, but I cannot do an "==" comparison because each el is different in every list, even if they start the same, so they're not seen as equal by Python.
I also tried a loop inside a loop but I don't know how to compare one element with ALL the elements of another list only IF the strings start in the same manner.
I also checked other SO threads but they seem to refer to comparisons between lists when elements are exactly the same, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things simple and readable, I would make use of a helper function (I named it `is_prefix_of_any`). Without this function we would have two nested loops, which is needlessly confusing. Checking whether a string is a prefix of another string is done with the [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function.

I also opted to create a new list instead of removing strings from `things_to_tweet`, because removing things from a list you're iterating over will often cause unexpected results.

```
# define a helper function that checks if any string in a list
# starts with another string
# we will use this to check if any string in items_on_queue starts
# with a string from things_to_tweet
def is_prefix_of_any(prefix, strings):
    for string in strings:
        if string.startswith(prefix):
            return True
    return False

# build a new list containing only the strings we want
things = []
for thing in things_to_tweet:
    if not is_prefix_of_any(thing, items_on_queue):
        things.append(thing)

print(things) # output: ['Playmobil is a toy']
```

A veteran would do this with much less code, but this should be a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Condition with String `startswith(..)`

```
[s for s in things_to_tweet if not any(i.startswith(s) for i in items_on_queue)] 
#Output:
#['Playmobil is a toy']
```